# How to feed range from org-table filled with strings to code-block via tblfm?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table

Following Situation:

- I would like to calculate some fields from an org-table filled with strings.
- There are many tables which all could share the same lisp-code.
- The lisp-code is rather complex and long.
- It should run for a single table multiple times, but with different parameters.
- I would like to share the org-document along with calculation-ability.

Is it possible to achive this? If so how to achieve this?

I have done some simple tests to show you where my problem is:

```
#+NAME: test3
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x="foobar"
(length x)
#+END_SRC

#+TBLNAME: test3-tbl
| blahbar |   |
| testi   | 7 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2='(org-sbe test3 (x $@1$1))
```

The above code works it takes one string from the table and prints its length into the table, fine.

Next code is also working:

```
#+NAME: test5
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x='(2 3)
(* (car x) (cadr x))
#+END_SRC

#+TBLNAME: test5-tbl
| 4 |  5 |
|---+----|
| 6 | 20 |
#+TBLFM: @>$1='(org-sbe test5)::@>$2='(org-sbe test5 (x @1$1..@1$2))
```

It takes a range of numbers from the table and does some calculation, fine.

Now I tried to combine the stuff from above, and there I hit the wall.
How to give a range (fields @1$1 to @1$2) from test-tbl4 to code-block test4?

```
#+NAME: test4
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x='("foobar" "barfoo")
(concat (car x) (cadr x))
#+END_SRC

#+TBLNAME: test4-tbl
| blahbar      | test   |
| foobarbarfoo | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: @>$1='(org-sbe test4)::@>$2='(org-sbe test4 (x $@1$1..$@1$2))
```

As you can see by `#ERROR` it is not working.

So my Questions:

1. How get table test4-tbl to work with code-block test4?
2. And could you please point me to the documentation where this is described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of a cell’s value as a string with the `$` prefix doesn’t seem to work for ranges of cells. Your example does work without the range reference though:

```
#+NAME: test4
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x='("foobar" "barfoo")
(concat (car x) (cadr x))
#+END_SRC

#+TBLNAME: test4-tbl
| blahbar      | test        |
| foobarbarfoo | blahbartest |
#+TBLFM: @>$1='(org-sbe test4)::@>$2='(org-sbe test4 (x $@1$1 $@1$2))
```

If you prefer range references, I’d change the code block to

```
#+NAME: test5
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var x='()
(mapconcat 'prin1-to-string x "")
#+END_SRC

#+TBLNAME: test4-tbl
| blahbar      | test        | another            |
| foobarbarfoo | blahbartest | blahbartestanother |
#+TBLFM: @>$3='(org-sbe test5 (x @1$1..@1$3))
```

Comment: The second part of your answer solves my problem, thanks. Do you have a clue where to find more information about constructs like "$@1$1" especially with the '$' in front. The org-mode manual does not seem to explain this.

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I did was turning on the `org-table-toggle-formula-debugger` to see what the range reference actually returned.

Answer (score 1):

As of the org-mode git version since [2018-03-19](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/c9d617b32278c04e114bd7c6375ca53636a005ba), you can pass a range via `org-sbe` as a list:

```
#+name: concat
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :eval yes
  (mapconcat #'identity x "")
#+end_src

| foo | bar | foobar |
#+TBLFM: $3 = '(org-sbe concat (x (list $1..$2)))
```

This will now work correctly even if the table cells contain quotes or backslashes.